# How to stop serving static files in Nodejs/expressjs?

Tags: node.js

I serve a temporary directory using

```
var express       = require("express");
var serveIndex    = require("serve-index");

app.use('/tmp_dir', express.static('/var/www/tmp'));
app.use('/tmp_dir', serveIndex('/var/www/tmp'));
```

At some point, I may delete /var/www/tmp and think it makes sense to stop serving its content both a static files and as an automatically built index page.  Is there a way to do so ?  I tried calling app.use with an undefined callback but it raises an error.

Thanks, Marc

Comment: Express does not provide a documented mechanism for removing routes that you've already installed.  You'd have to hack into the route list to remove one or create a custom middleware that uses logic to decide whether to call the `express.static()` handler or not.

Answer (score 0):

Based on jfriend00's answer, I have installed a first handler that tests if the directory exists :

```
app.use('/tmp_dir', function(request, response, next) {
  if (fs.existsSync('/var/www/tmp') === true) {
    next();
  } else {
    response.end('DELETED');
    next('route');
  }
});
app.use('/tmp_dir', express.static('/var/www/tmp'));
app.use('/tmp_dir', serveIndex('/var/www/tmp'));
```

Comment: Why would you want to call `next('route')` when you've already sent the response?  I think you just remove the `next('route')` or remove the `response.end()`?  One or the other.